# Meaningful word detection

Tags: nlp, semantics

I'm trying to filter only meaningful words from a list of words. Some of the words will be gibberish and i want to filter them out. I'm curious if there is a library for this in a common language like python or nodejs. It would be great if the library supports different languages (turkish in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for stopwords list? If so, you can refer to this post [NLTK available languages for stopwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54573853/nltk-available-languages-for-stopwords)